# Netlogo: How can I make a turtle of one type pick to make interation with one turtle of the sencond type following two criterions?

Tags: netlogo, interaction

I have 4 breeds of turtles: emps1, emps2, emps3, and emps4. There are 4 Emps3.
They produce 2 products and determine their prices. Emps4 needs to buy 2 products (not necessarily of the same emp3). They must pick which products to buy based on the product price (lowers one) and the distance between emp4 and emp3.

I don't know how to combine these two pieces of information in order to make each turtle of type emps4 identify the two products with the best benefits.
I thought in create lists that combine the information such as, but it has a heavy programming cost.

Comment: Please have a look at the [suggestions for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the overview of [how to include some example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)- you'll have more luck on here if viewers can have a look at what you've tried etc.

Comment: We will need a bit more context here. What is the purpose of your model? How many turtles of each type are there? Is there a fixed limit for prices? A fixed limit, for example, would allow you to only check turtles up until a certain radius, since anything beyond that radius can't possibly offer a better deal.